# How can I use TortoiseSVN on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn

How can I use TortoiseSVN on windows. I am Using Visual Studio 2010.
we are 5 people want to work on same project.the project will be  on server and  every person access the project from server and make changes. 
I also want to make roll management.
E.g
On server there are more then one project and every person can see assigned project.
can I configure svn with visual studio ?

Comment: Hm, I'm a bit unclear what your question is. The only one I really see is: _"can I configure svn with visual studio "_, which is a bit ambiguous: do you want to use Visual Studio to _configure svn_, or do you want Visual Studio _configured to use svn_?

Comment: I want Visual Studio configured to use svn.

Comment: Do you have a subversion in your server (or elsewhere) already installed and running your repositories?

Comment: I Install TortoiseSVN and visualSvn on my server and my local machine I Configure it locally but still I can't get Solution from server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/). It is a Subversion integration plug-in for Visual Studio. It has also a Community License

Comment: First I have to install subversion ?

Comment: Do you have a subversion in your server (or elsewhere) already installed and running your repositories?

Comment: I Install TortoiseSVN and visualSvn on my server and my local machine I Configure it locally but still I can't get Solution from server.

Comment: Two clarifying questions: 1. Did you install visualsvn server(!) version on your server?
2. Did you create and configure access to your repositories?

Comment: 1. I am Using visulaSVN 4.0.2.
2. I don't Create configure access.

Comment: Thanks for helping .
Now I successfully configure it.

Answer (score 1):

I Configure tortoisesvn on my server and on local machine.
1. Install **TortoiseSVN** 
2. Install  [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/)
3. Install  [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/)
4.Create User in VisualSvn server Manager. 
5.Create Repositories.
6. assign user to repositories or sub folder to give access to user 
7.Make Project and add it to Subversion.
 
8.from Local Machine Get Solution from Subversion.
Write the path of project Like This  protocol://Server:port/svn/root/TestProject1/

Answer (score 0):

How to use TortoiseSVN on Windows:

1. Install TortoiseSVN
2. Reboot if you feel paranoid
3. Use TortoiseSVN

What's your *real* question?

Comment: After installation how i can access it from remote desktop?

Comment: That doesn't even make any sense. You use it over remote desktop just like you use it locally. Right-click on a working copy. Choose the option you want from the TortoiseSVN menu. Done.

Comment: I Install TortoiseSVN and visualSvn on my server and my local machine I Configure it locally but still I can't get Solution from server.